# Fetch API result isn't showing in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a react app and I want to fetch an API, here's the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  let [ quote, setQuote ] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://zenquotes.io/api/random')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setQuote(data[0]))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <main>
      {quote}
    </main>
  )
}
```

The page shows blank and when I make the same fetch API method in a js file and run it with node it runs perfectly, please help!

i've tried using axios, and add proxy to my package.json

Comment: `data[0]` would be an object, have you tried `{quote.q}` ?

Comment: of course i have

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: i'm coding on a phone, i have no idea how to open a console

Answer (score 2):

I quickly pasted the above code into a codesandbox and, based on the errors I'm seeing in the console, you likely have a CORS issue on your hands. If that's the case, there is not much you can do strictly from the front-end, especially on a phone.

There are ways around CORS issues (which is essentially a default whitelisting mechanic from back-end to front-end on different domains to ensure better security) but you would need to either contact the service provider to allow access to the domain you are running on, run it through a backend proxy running in Node/backend tech of choice, or in a project setup with dev tools that have proxying configuration built in (which would ultimately be running a Node.js proxy pattern to accomplish the task).

Comment: yes, after i read the documentation deeper, i found that it requires me to put API key in order to consume the API, i tried fetching the API using 3 different languages and not in browser context, they all were working, do you have any API recommendation for me to practice, sir.